# set_password() is not working in Django Serializer create() function

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I tried all existing solutions for my issue and none worked.

The code is working well through postman, yet the password in not hashed in SQLite table.

The code is as follows:

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    class Role(models.IntegerChoices):
        SUPERUSER = 1
        ADMIN = 2
        MANAGEMENT = 3
        HEAD = 4
        TRAINEE = 5
        PROVIDER = 6
        TRAINER = 7

    role = models.IntegerField(null=False, verbose_name='role', choices=Role.choices, default=Role.TRAINEE)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255, verbose_name='email')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='password')
    username = None

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['role']
```

#### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response


class RegisterView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

#### serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'email', 'password', 'role']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

        # validate_password = make_password

        def create(self, validated_data):
            password = validated_data.pop('password')
            instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
            if password is not None:
                instance.set_password(password)
            instance.save()
            return instance
```

Please if you may support me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error in this code is that the **create()** function is indented under the **Meta** Class.

**Create()** must be under the **UserSerializer()** Class.